# Binary tree implementation using Swift enum

Tags: swift

I'm doing some experiments with Swift enums to become more familiarized with them and have implemented a rudimentary binary tree. It works when adding up to three items, but adding more beyond that doesn't change it and I couldn't see why it wasn't working.

Here's the code:

```
protocol TreeProtocol {
    mutating func insert(value: Int)
    func walk()
}


enum Tree:TreeProtocol {
    case Empty
    case Leaf(Int)
    case Node(Int, TreeProtocol?, TreeProtocol?)

    init(){
        self = .Empty;
    }

    init(value: Int) {
        self = .Leaf(value)
    }

    init(value: Int, left:TreeProtocol?, right:TreeProtocol?){
        self = .Node(value, left, right);
    }

    mutating func insert(value: Int) {
        switch self {
        case .Empty:
            self = .Leaf(value)

        case .Leaf(let currentNodeValue):
            let newTree = Tree(value: value) // var here generates a warning
            if value < currentNodeValue {
                self = .Node(currentNodeValue, newTree, .None)
            }
            else {
                self = .Node(currentNodeValue, .None, newTree)
            }

        case let .Node(currentNodeValue, leftNode, rightNode):
            if (value < currentNodeValue) {
                if leftNode == nil {
                    let newTree = Tree(value: value)
                    self = .Node(currentNodeValue, newTree, rightNode)
                }
                else {
                    var l = leftNode! // unable to call leftNode!.insert() directly
                    l.insert(value)
                }
            }
            else {
                if rightNode == nil {
                    let newTree = Tree(value: value)
                    self = .Node(currentNodeValue, leftNode, newTree)
                }
                else {
                    var r = rightNode!
                    r.insert(value)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func walk() {
        switch self {
        case .Empty:
            print("Empty")
        case .Leaf (let value):
            print("\(value), ")
        case .Node(let value, let leftNode, let rightNode):
            if leftNode != nil {
                leftNode!.walk()
            }
            print("\(value) ")
            if (rightNode != nil) {
                rightNode!.walk()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if I run the following tests:

```
    var tree = Tree();
    tree.walk()

    tree.insert(100)
    tree.walk()

    tree.insert(50)
    tree.walk()

    tree.insert(150)
    tree.walk()

    tree.insert(25)
    tree.walk()
```

The output is:

```
    Empty

    100

    50,
    100

    50,
    100,
    150

    50,
    100,
    150
```

The 25 value is not getting added to the tree

(This code is a bit inelegant, its just the first iteration, there's several ugly parts in there that could be improved and beautified. Waiting for recursive enum functionality to be added to the Xcode beta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you already have an answer, but I really like your implementation and thought I'd provide the code for implementing @Wain's solution and also streamline some of the nested `if-else` logic.

It involves a slight modification for the protocol, so that `insert` returns a value:

```
protocol TreeProtocol {
    mutating func insert(value: Int) -> TreeProtocol
    func walk()
}
```

And then the `insert` function can be rewritten like this:

```
mutating func insert(value: Int) -> TreeProtocol {
    switch self {
    case .Empty:
        self = .Leaf(value)

    case .Leaf(let currentNodeValue):
        let newTree = Tree(value: value)
        self = value < currentNodeValue
            ? .Node(currentNodeValue, newTree, .None)
            : .Node(currentNodeValue, .None, newTree)

    case var .Node(currentNodeValue, leftNode, rightNode):
        self = value < currentNodeValue
            ? .Node(currentNodeValue, leftNode?.insert(value) ?? Tree(value: value), rightNode)
            : .Node(currentNodeValue, leftNode, rightNode?.insert(value) ?? Tree(value: value))
    }
    return self
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know my code was inelegant, its was just the first iteration and your streamlining is neater. I'm looking forward to re-writing it again without using the protocol once Xcode supports recursive enums.

Comment: I only took the time because I liked how you did it and I plan on stealing it :)

Comment: You might be stealing something old-style once recursive enums come out and then you'll get a reputation for being old fashioned.

Comment: Do I get reputation points for that? An 'Old Fashioned' badge, maybe? Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Because you're mutating the internal nodes and that is actually creating a copy of them. That copy is never inserted into the tree, it's just thrown away after being modified. If after inserting into `l` and `r` you reinsert those nodes (with `self = .Node(currentNodeValue, l, rightNode)` and `self = .Node(currentNodeValue, leftNode, r)` respectively) then the tree as a whole will get updated. It's a by-value / by-reference issue.

Comment: Not sure if you can pattern match and get a by-reference so you can update inline without needing to insert a copy...

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain further what you mean by your comment.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to make the enum values available by reference, either in the definition or the pattern match

Comment: `enum`s are always value types. If you use an `enum` for your binary tree you will always be using value types.